# Javascript div hide not working

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, html

I am trying to hide a comment form on [my wordpress blog](http://www.stefan-wright.com/blog.php) (although the page isn't the wordpress blog, I just get the posts).

If I have comments then the hide/show will work for the form and for the comments. If I have no comments the function doesn't work and i'm not sure why.

If anybody can help I can upload the php files that show the posts (blog.php) and the comments page (comments.php) that is generated within the wordpress theme.

**EDIT:** PHP code removed as not relevant to error. Relevant HTML code as follows:

```
...
<body class="home blog logged-in custom-background">
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery("#content img").addClass("imageSeven");
   });
</script>

...

<a id="replytitle" href="javascript:togglecommentform('replyform17');">Show Comment Form</a>
<div id="replyform17" style="display:block;">
   ...
</div>

...

<a id="replytitle" href="javascript:togglecommentform('replyform6');">Show Comment Form</a>
<div id="replyform6" style="display:block;">
   ...
</div>

...
```

Comment: Can you please post your code here rather than a link (this fits in with the expected SO question format). If its JavaScript that's causing your issue, then we only need that (plus the HTML in question)

Comment: And means also that when the site's fixed/modified the question *remains useful* to subsequent visitors. Incidentally, PHP is irrelevant to JavaScript (for the most part) as JavaScript is client-side and works on the DOM, rendered from the HTML as seen by the browser. Post your relevant rendered HTML and JavaScript here, please.

Comment: I have added snippets @beardtwizzle

Comment: Now you went to the other extreme. Please cut down your code to the part that gives you trouble. Also an error message or a precise question would improve the quality of this question.

Comment: @Dan The reason for uploading the whole of the comments.php is that I dont know if there is something in there causing this issue. The exact issue I am experiencing is that if I have no blog post comments the hide/show doesnt function, but if I have a comment on any of the posts the hide/show does function. I hope this makes things clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem, in that the output (view source) has a reference to jQuery right at the top:

```
<body class="home blog logged-in custom-background">
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       jQuery("#content img").addClass("imageSeven");
    });
 </script>
```

Some points on this:

1. Because you don't include a reference to jQuery anywhere - this will cause an error, meaning that even if the rest of you JavaScript is valid, it will fail to run.
2. You don't need `jQuery(document).ready...` if you move all your JavaScript to the bottom of the page (just before the `</body>` end tag.)

Your main problem seems to be a confused code structure. Based on the messy code you have (no offense), I would recommend using a library like jQuery:

---

**Step 1: Remove all the JavaScript you have in that page.**

By the looks of things, that just means the `<script>` block thats right beneath your `<body>` tag.

**Step 2: Replace these `<a>` start tags:**

```
<a id="replytitle" href="javascript:togglecommentform('replyform17');">
<a id="replytitle" href="javascript:togglecommentform('replyform6');">
```

With these:

```
<a id="replytitle17" href="#">
<a id="replytitle6" href="#">
```

**Step 3: Just before the `</body>` tag, include the following:**

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       var images = $('#content img');
       if (images.length > 0) { images.addClass("imageSeven"); }
       $('#replytitle17').click(function() { $('#replyform17').toggle(); });
       $('#replytitle6').click(function() { $('#replyform6').toggle(); });
    </script>
```

This should achieve everything your page has, in jQuery.

Comment: +1, I would have thought jQuery was natively included in a WP install

Comment: Thanks @beardtwizzle, I will have a look at this. The JQuery you mention was placed in by the wordpress theme I have utilized across the site and because I am not a seasoned pro at developing I didnt realise there was an issue.

Comment: @Stefan - the best way of checking this, is to use a browser such as Firefox/Chrome and check its "Web Developer console" - if you do this, you'll see some red text saying something like "jQuery is undefined"

Comment: Also the "replyform#" is dynamically generated by php so that when opening the comment form for one post it didnt open or hide it for all of the posts. Anyway of adjusting your jQuery so that it can be used in the same way?

Comment: @beardtwizzle, thanks for your help but I have just figured out from looking at the chrome console that when there were no comments were present my javescript wasnt put on the page (from the comments.php page). I adjusted my php code and it is now functioning. And I am going to remove the jquery after the body tag as I don't use it.